# Sum of BigDecimal array is always zero

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've got an array of BigDecimal in Java and I would like to calculate the sum of all the element of this array. I am trying the following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal[] res = {
            new BigDecimal("20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722")
           ,new BigDecimal("53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690")};
        BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        //BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal("0");
        for(BigDecimal s : res) sum.add(s);
        System.out.println(sum); 
    }
```

My issue is that the sum variable is zero:

```
run:
0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I've created the sum var in two ways but both ways give the same zero value.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
for(BigDecimal s : res) sum.add(s);
```

to

```
for(BigDecimal s : res) {
    sum = sum.add(s);
}
```

`BigDecimal` is an immutable class, so `add()` returns a new `BigDecimal` instance, which you have to assign to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal objects are immutable. The add method returns a new BigDecimal object containing the sum. You're throwing this sum away and keep on working with your unmodified initial value.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), you will see that the `add` method of `BigDecimal` doesn't update the value of the instance, but returns a new one. Please try to reaffect the result of `add` to the variable `sum`:

```java
sum = sum.add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following instead of sum.add(s);

sum = sum.add(s); //inside the loop

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could as well perform a reduction on the array, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal[] res = { 
                new BigDecimal("20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722"),
                new BigDecimal("53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690") 
            };
    // use a stream to sum up all the values
    BigDecimal sum = Arrays.stream(res)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b));
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(sum.toString());
}
```

The result of this reduction is

```
74353138206606525974804725742415345026517134941412
```